# Hashmap Capacity vs Time Tradeoff

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a very straight forward question but I am not able to figure it out. The question is:

If we increase the size of array inside map (that is, the capacity of a map), it will increase the execution time (of `put` & `get` methods) ?

Comment: Execution time of what?

Comment: Execution time of put and get

Comment: If a map is with a large array, doesn't mean it will have a slower get and put. Hash collision is what can make a map slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

[Look the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), the only thing that can impact time of `put` and `get` is the `hashCode` implementation.

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

The impact occurs when you have [Hash Collision](https://www.quora.com/How-is-collision-handled-in-HashMap). This occurs when you have the same hash code for two different objects.

---

The HashMap will calculate the position based on the hashCode, if you set a small **initialCapacity** and a very large **loadFactor** it will occurs the hash collision, so it will create a list in some positions. That means that the `get` will run over the list of crashed elements, not all the lists.

So imagine that you have a array of N position for M elements. It will in the worst case be `O(max(1, M/N))`. So `N` SHOULD be greater than `M`.

If you look the [HashMap implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29), it calls the resize operation if the size gets too big (75% of the total capacity). So the initial capacity is not a final capacity and the capacity will always bigger with the grow of the map.

The only problem with the initial capacity is store a memory before it is needed. This can cause a memory leak!

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

Comment: as the number of items per bucket increases (the size much larger than the number of buckets) cost of `put` and `get` will start increasing at a rate proportional to **N/number of buckets** so essentially O(N)

Comment: Should also be noted clearly that having a hashmap with significantly fewer buckets than elements will also worsen the performance, since more items will be within one bucket

Comment: Yes, but you have the adjust the size of your array. If you set it small to reduce footprint, you will pay that with time. You should use capacity at least greater that the number of elements you will use.

Comment: Big arrays do not reserve big spaces. But small arrays can take too long times.

Comment: @Victor that's exactly my point. We don't know how many items OP has, and what number of buckets he wants to have. The definition of "a lot of buckets" really depends on the amount of elements. 300 buckets is definitely a lot if you have one element, but it's nearly not enough if you have a 100k elements.

Comment: @Cargeh, the HashMap actually do the `resize ` operation when it gets bigger than it's capacity. So it will improbably that this occurs because of it capacity. Initialise the capacity only say to the Map it initial capacity.

Comment: @Victor it doesn't resize when it gets bigger than capacity, it resizes based on `loadFactor`. If I set it high enough, it might never resize, even if there are x2, x3, x10 more elements than buckets. OP has given us no info on that. Also, we should distinguish discussing `java.util.HashMap` and `HashMap` as an abstract data structure.

Comment: @Cargeh, the loadFactor says when it will resize. But it is true that resize when gets bigger. If you set loadFactor to 10000, you are saying that you want destroy your get operation. It is your choice.

Comment: Let the default value and be happy.

Comment: The only thing you should be aware it that if you are using own Objects as key. Reimplement equals and hashCode as contract: https://www.ideyatech.com/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/

Answer (score 0):

While there are some "micro-optimizations", what you generally want to look after is the [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

This generally depends on the number of collisions that you may have. In order to it properly in Java, you need to override the **hashCode()** method. But pay attention that, if you do that, you should also override the **equals()** method as well.

A quick info why [overriding only hashCode() method?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/331568)

Also pay attention that, although the best-case scenario is O(1) and worst-case scenario is O(n), a proper implementation of overriding hashCode() method will result with much better performance than the brief observation initially suggests when you base your opinion on best-case and worst-case scenarios.

In theory, if you have bigger amount of total combinations (in your words: "capacity of a map"), you will actually be likely to *decrease* the number of potential hash code collisions and the since the actual increase would be preferred only when you have very large sets of objects, the increase of potential hash code combinations would likely decrease the execution time overall.

Answer (score 0):

Write a benchmark and find out, everything else is speculation.

In theory the `#get` and `#put` operations may get a little bit faster as the chance for hash collisions is reduced. Also the chance that the `HashMap` has to be grown is reduced, ideally it will never have to be grown, speeding up `#put`. Whether these are actually measurable is a different question.

If the array is bigger changes of everything being in the CPU cache are lower, in theory making `#get` and `#put` a bit slower. Again, whether this is actually measurable is a different question.

Comment: Big O notation is not "speculation"

Comment: Big O only talks about scalability, not performance. And even then there is the chance you get it wrong or forgot about something.

Answer (score -2):

Yes: http://java-performance.info/large-hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove/

According to this benchmark, generally anything you do with a map will become slower the larger it is. Choosing the right map for each job can help mitigate this.

In case you are talking only about capacity, not size, perhaps this benchmark is what you are looking for: https://pzemtsov.github.io/2015/12/14/choosing-the-hash-maps-capacity.html

Comment: Having a "large map" with a lot of collisions is not the same as increasing the numbe of buckets (array size). You're right in a certain way, but this is not what OP is asking about

Comment: @Cargeh can you help?

Comment: Andreas, you're confusing the number of buckets and the number of elements within one bucket. Your answer is not very helpful and might be confusing. Also, the author is not looking for a benchmark.